# Replace Blueprintjs css with Bootstrap css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-2, blueprintjs

I'm using [Blueprint](http://blueprintjs.com/) React components inside a page that uses Bootstrap 2 framework. I would like to replace Blueprint component styling with Bootstrap. What would be the best approach to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this request is so expensive as to be impractical. You'd have to rewrite *all* of blueprint.css to use Bootstrap colors and concepts. Your best bet is to *not* do this--use *either* Blueprint or Bootstrap.

We started Blueprint back in the day cuz Bootstrap wasn't cutting it for us in our React world.